# Created new project with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Set up initial tables, for rudimentary login and "remember-me".

However hibernate is failing to create tables based on my annotated classes ... and I can not understand why. Here are the relevant snippets of my `applicationContext.xml` located under `/WEB-INF/` :

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/database.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

```
<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
            p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
            p:acquireIncrement="5"
            p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
            p:maxPoolSize="100"
            p:maxStatements="50"
            p:minPoolSize="10" />

<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

and `hibernate.cfg.xml` that is located under `/src/main/resources` and gets copied to `/WEB-INF/classe`s by maven:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">Create</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and my classes look like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Index;
@Entity
@Table(name = "office")
public class Office extends Base {..
```

My app starts OK and I can even log in (as I have an in memory service as well). However no database tables are created(accessed from back-end), and the persistent login I also created does not work because the relevant table is not created (I actually get an error when attempting to log out stating *bad sql no table persistent_login exists*).  No errors occur on app start up.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Which version of hibernate you are using.

Comment: @NimChimpsky How does your logfile look like when you add `<logger name="org.springframework.context">
  <level value="debug" />
 </logger>`? Check component scan and hiberate log messages.

Comment: try small c for `create` in hbm2ddl.auto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn on trace logging for org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl. This would show you the DDL Hibernate is generating when it creates your schema.

From the Hibernate Source:

```
String autoSchemaExport = properties.getProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO);
        if ( "validate".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) settings.setAutoValidateSchema(true);
        if ( "update".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) settings.setAutoUpdateSchema(true);
        if ( "create".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) settings.setAutoCreateSchema(true);
        if ( "create-drop".equals(autoSchemaExport) ) {
            settings.setAutoCreateSchema(true);
            settings.setAutoDropSchema(true);
    }
```

Looks like you need a small c on create (as pointed out by @aishwaryaless)